# How to add on menu class "active" after page load?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu').click(function(){
    $('.menu').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
}); //end ready
```

It's my code and I want add class after page is load.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on usage.

`$(document).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').addClass('active');
});
```

`$(window).load()` will execute when the page is fully loaded including graphics.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.menu').addClass('active');
});
```

Reference: [Jquery Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a created fiddle that will assign active class to the first li's anchor tag. Below is the code:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="menu">მთავარი</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about.php" class="menu">ფონდის შესახებ</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="blog.php" class="menu">პროექტები</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php" class="menu">გალერეა</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.php" class="menu">კონტაქტი</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.menu').click(function () {
                 $('.menu').removeClass("active");
                 $(this).addClass("active");
            });
            $('#smoothmenu1 ul > li:first-child a').addClass('active');
    });
```

Here is the jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/shrawanlakhe/xudvunpx/

Answer (score -1):

Just add below css

ul li a{color:black;}

ul li a.active{color:red}